# Case-insensitive order on nested properties

Tags: grails, case-insensitive, createcriteria

Say, I have two domain classes:

```
class Foo {
   Bar bar

   Long baz
}

class Bar {
   String name
}
```

And I have a call coming into a `createCriteria` that wants to sort by the Bar's name (or any other valid property that the client wants to sort by), ignoring the case.  I've been able to reduce it to:

```
Foo.createCriteria().list() {
    //...
    bar {
        order((params.sortOrder == 'asc' ? 
            Order.asc('name') : // 'name' is a variable in the real code 
            Order.desc('name')
        ).ignoreCase())
    }
}
```

but when the sort property is nested (ie a property of `bar`), I get an exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: Foo
```

I've found these related Grails bugs [GRAILS-8182](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8182), [GRAILS-9171](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9171), [GRAILS-3911](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3911) which make it seem like there is a combination of bugs that make what I want to do, not possible.

Is there a way to do case-insensitive sorting on nested properties in `createCriteria`?  I realize I can sort either on the client, or on the Groovy list, but I really would prefer not to have to reinvent the wheel (especially since it would be a really ugly wheel).

I am using Grails 2.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question when trying to solve a similar issue related to sorting in grails. Maybe in the meanwhile a solution has already been found. If not, I wanted to suggest you tried the following:

```
Foo.createCriteria().list() {
    createAlias("bar","_b")
    order("_b.name", (params.sortOrder == "asc")?"asc":"desc")
}
```

In this way you should be able to order instances of `Foo` by `bar.name`